# applying a function to pandas column without getting SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

Dataset looks like this:

|  | headline_text |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | aba decides against community broadcasting lic... |
| 1 | act fire witnesses must be aware of defamation |
| 2 | a g calls for infrastructure protection summit |
| 3 | air nz staff in aust strike for pay rise |
| 4 | air nz strike to affect australian travellers |

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Function to clean the headline.
def clean_text(headline):
    '''
    Step 1: Lemmatization of words using spacy
    Step 2: Include words whose length >= 3.
    Step 3: Join all lemmatized words.
    '''
    word_tokens = nlp(headline)
    tokens = []
    for token in word_tokens:
        if len(token) >= 3:
            tokens.append(token.text)
    
    x = " ".join(tokens)
    return x

# Try 1:
# df_small['headline_cleaned_text'] = df_small['headline_text'].map(clean_text)

# Try 2:
df_small['headline_cleaned_text'] = df_small.apply(lambda x: clean_text(x['headline_text']), axis = 1)
df_small.head()
```

The output is fine, but comes with a `warning`.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_small['headline_cleaned_text'] = df_small.apply(lambda x: clean_text(x['headline_text']), axis = 1)
```

How to get rid of this warning in efficient way?

Comment: use .loc , df_small.loc['headline_cleaned_test']=..

Comment: thanks for looking into the issue, the solution you suggested to me, it still gives the same warning to me. not sure why.

Comment: even .loc[:,'headline_cleaned_test']=... gives the same warning?

Comment: Yes.
```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_small.loc['headline_cleaned_text'] = df_small.apply(lambda x: clean_text(x['headline_text']), axis = 1)
```